# A line cutting an ellipse in two points, finding the equation of ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I have a question that says that:

A line $x+2y+4 = 0$ cutting the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ in points whose eccentric angles are $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ subtends a right angle at the origin, then the equation of the ellipse is:

The answer is given as $$\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$

Now, the solution the book provides was by first considering the points as $(a \cos\theta,b \sin\theta)$, and using the values of 2 given angles, and then equating it with the slope of the line, and thus they found the relation that $a = 2b$ and then what they did was homogenise the equation of the line with the ellipse and set the coeffcient of $x^2 + y^2$ = 0 which is the condition for subtending $90^\circ$ at the center, and they get $b^2 = 4 $

This solution is perfectly fine, and I'm able to understand it, but what I tried was, since the line cuts the ellipse at the given points, I took the points as $(a \cos\theta,b \sin\theta)$ and then I put the values of given angles. Then I put the points into the equation of the line as this should satisfy the equation of the line as these points lie on it.

But this yields a different value of $b$, and as far as I can tell neither of the calculations have had a calculation mistake. I dont know why my solution is wrong or what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the problem has no solution. The intersection points are:
$$
A=(a\cos30°,a\sin30°)=\bigg({\sqrt3\over2}a,{1\over2}b\bigg);
\quad
B=(a\cos60°,b\sin60°)=\bigg({1\over2}a,{\sqrt3\over2}b\bigg);
$$
but $\angle AOB$ cannot be a right angle, because it is easy to compute:
$$
\cos\angle AOB={A\cdot B\over|A|\ |B|}=
{\sqrt3(a^2+b^2)\over2\sqrt{3a^2+b^2}\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}}\ne0.
$$

EDIT.

The given solution uses the eccentric angles only to find that $a=2b$. But this is not specific of the angles $30°$ and $60°$: in fact the points where the line intersects the ellipse given as solution correspond to eccentric angles of $180°$ and $270°$.

Your method is perfectly fine, but it cannot find a valid solution in this case because the given line lies in the second, third and fourth quadrant, whereas the points corresponding to eccentric angles of $30°$ and $60°$ lie in the first quadrant.

Comment: Then what may be the mistake in their solution? The method? Because what the book did seemed reasonable to me. Like the steps made sense

Comment: This is the solution that the book also had: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-the-linedisplaystyle-x2y40-cutting-the-ellipse-in-points-whose-eccentric-angles-aredisplaystyle-30circ-anddisplaystyle/

Comment: @Techie5879 What do they mean by "subtends a right angle at the origin"? Do they mean $\angle AOB=90°$ or something else?

Comment: Yes that's what they mean. AOB is 90 deg

Comment: With respect to your latest edit, then why do I get b= 4-4√3 by putting the values in the equation of the line? Does it give extraneous solutions then?

Comment: @Techie5879 That's not compatible with eccentric angles of 30° and 60°: just draw a sketch if you are not convinced by my calculation.

Comment: @Techie5879 You get a negative value for $b$ because the problem is impossible.

Comment: Yeah I did and something seemed wrong with the problem to me too. What I want to know is how did they get an answer that's different than mine by homogenising the eqn of the line with the curve. What did they assume wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what would be wrong if I homogenised the equation? Like, why does it yield a different value than mine?

Comment: @Techie5879 I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Really helps man